# Replace X linebreaks with comma and delete every Nth linebreak

Tags: bash, csv

I have records in a text file formatted in the following way:

```
Record1
Record1
Record1
Record1

Record2
Record2
Record2
Record2

...
```

I need to convert this file to CSV by replacing the first 3 line breaks with a comma and removing the 4th, resulting in output like this:

```
Record1,Record1,Record1,Record1
Record2,Record2,Record2,Record2

...
```

What's the best way to do this in Bash, where best is more about robustness than performance - the task won't be done often, but does need to allow for the values to contain virtually any characters apart from whitespace and linebreaks.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @FrankThomas I hadn't *tried* anything, because I hadn't found any solutions that met my requirements, and don't know `awk`, `sed` and similar tools well enough to risk the integrity of my data. On the other hand, I *searched* for lots of things before asking the question, but it's never before been a requirement for asking a question to include that history in the answer.

Comment: @HashimAziz it has always been expected on this site that people "show their homework", as it were, listing any efforts they have made to solve the problem themselves. This serve many purposes that may vary from question to question. Some of these can be: focusing the question and adding specificity and clarity, letting the community know what NOT to suggest as solutions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use awk for this

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS = "\n"; RS = ""; OFS = ","} {$1 = $1; print}' file
```

Setting RS to the empty string means that 2 or more newlines separate records.
The field separator is a single newline.

`$1 = $1` is an idiomatic way to force awk to rewrite the current record using the output field separator.

Comment: I can't say I fully understand it but I just tested this solution and it does appear to work without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun of it, a python one-liner[1] to create the expected result:

```
$ python -c "\
import sys;eol='END\n';\
lines=[line.strip()+',' if len(line)>1 else eol for line in sys.stdin];\
print(''.join(lines)+eol)" \
<records
```

lines:

1. launch python with a literal string
2. get access to sys.stdin, set line ending constant
3. use a list comprehension to read in the lines from stdin while   checking for empty lines, replacing these with the eol-marker
4. with a list of lines created, join the lines, print them
5. from where to read lines (command line redirection)

As you paste the text above (without the leading $) into a (bash) terminal you will get this...

```
Record1,Record1,Record1,Record1,END
Record2,Record2,Record2,Record2,END
Record1,Record1,Record1,Record1,END
Record2,Record2,Record2,Record2,END
Record1,Record1,Record1,Record1,END
Record2,Record2,Record2,Record2,END
```

... when reading from 'records' containing the sample text (repeated)...

It is a simple step to remove all those ",END"; e.g.  pipe it all into sed, for example;
append `| sed -re "s/,END$//"` to the last line.

*[1] The above is best typed on a single line, just skip the `\`'s, those were added for better readability HERE.*

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/installing-miller/) and running

```
mlr --n2t --headerless-tsv-output --from input.txt \
put '$id=$1' then skip-trivial-records then \
nest --ivar "," -f 1 then \
cut -x -f id
```

you get

```
Record1,Record1,Record1,Record1
Record2,Record2,Record2,Record2
```

Some notes:

- `skip-trivial-records` to remove empty lines;
- `nest --ivar "," -f 1` to merge the records values, separating them by `,`